# design pattern for Comparison of Revision

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there any design pattern or an existing product for 'Comparison of Revision'?

Say I have an end user who wrote a detailed document (long text) and many users are adding/removing text and eventually there's a final product. My goal is to show the 'evolution' of the text with emphasis on different versions.

The intuitive approach is save each version and compare it to the previous one but I don't want to duplicated text for each version. I wonder what pattern (or product) should be used in this case?

This needs to be integrated in the application we have and not as an external product such as git/svn.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a design pattern per se, but sounds a little like you want to write a version control system-ish program? Could look into how things like git are implemented for a start.

Comment: Have you considered something like [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to use version control such as SVN or git.

**EDIT**
If you really want to re-implement how version control software performs diffs, you can look at the code.

the book *Beautiful Code* has a chapter by one of the SVN authors on how SVN implements diff (with lots of actual code).  that would be a good start.

http://www.red-bean.com/kfogel/beautiful-code/bc-chapter-02.html

Comment: I need to integrate it in my application. So git/svn will not work. Thanks